# How can I optimize the dplyr code by group if all calculations are the same

Tags: r, optimization, dplyr, summarize

I have the following data frame, which is a subset of a much larger one containing over 3 million rows.

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,4,4,1,4,1,3,1,3,2,4,2,1,3,2,4),
              SubGroup = c("A","A","C","B","C","A","B","C","C","A","B","C","C","A","B","C","A","A","B","A","C","C","B","B","C"),
              Type = c("Z","Y","Z","X","X","Y","Z","X","Z","Y","Y","Y","X","Y","Z","X","X","Z","Y","X","Z","Z","Y","X","Y"),
              Value = c(4,7,2,8,4,6,1,8,3,6,3,6,3,5,6,7,3,2,7,4,9,4,7,8,1),
              Dup = c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1))
```

Per Group, there are five different formulas that I want to calculate. 
1) A sum of Value by SubGroup
2) A sum of Value by SubGroup and Dup
3) A sum of Value by SubGroup and Type Z
4) A sum of Value by SubGroup and Type Y
5) A sum of Value by SubGroup and Type X

Here is the code that I currently have using dplyr:

```
result <- df %>%
 group_by(Group) %>%
 summarise(SubGroup.A.Total = sum(Value[SubGroup=="A"]),
        SubGroup.A.Dup = sum(Value[SubGroup=="A" & Dup==1]),
        SubGroup.A.TypeZ = sum(Value[SubGroup=="A" & Type=="Z"]),
        SubGroup.A.TypeY = sum(Value[SubGroup=="A" & Type=="Y"]),
        SubGroup.A.TypeX = sum(Value[SubGroup=="A" & Type=="X"]),
        SubGroup.B.Total = sum(Value[SubGroup=="B"]),
        SubGroup.B.Dup = sum(Value[SubGroup=="B" & Dup==1]),
        SubGroup.B.TypeZ = sum(Value[SubGroup=="B" & Type=="Z"]),
        SubGroup.B.TypeY = sum(Value[SubGroup=="B" & Type=="Y"]),
        SubGroup.B.TypeX = sum(Value[SubGroup=="B" & Type=="X"]),
        SubGroup.C.Total = sum(Value[SubGroup=="C"]),
        SubGroup.C.Dup = sum(Value[SubGroup=="C" & Dup==1]),
        SubGroup.C.TypeZ = sum(Value[SubGroup=="C" & Type=="Z"]),
        SubGroup.C.TypeY = sum(Value[SubGroup=="C" & Type=="Y"]),
        SubGroup.C.TypeX = sum(Value[SubGroup=="C" & Type=="X"]))
```

However, I really want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this, both from a run time and number of lines perspective? Since I am in essence looping the same five formulas by SubGroup, I imagine there is a much simpler way of writing this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses `pivot_wider`, which so far is only available in the dev version of `tidyr`.

You are grouping by `SubGroup` for all the variables you want to calculate, so it's worth adding that to the `group_by`. For some of the variables you're also grouping by `Type`, so I guess you could do a separate grouping by `Group, SubGroup, Type` and join those variables back in, but it's not clear if that's worth it.

Sticking to just `group_by(Group, SubGroup)`, you can do:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Group, SubGroup) %>%
    summarize(
        Total = sum(Value),
        Dup = sum(Value[Dup == 1]),
        X = sum(Value[Type == "X"]),
        Y = sum(Value[Type == "Y"]),
        Z = sum(Value[Type == "Z"])
    ) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = SubGroup,
        values_from = c(-Group, -SubGroup)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Marius 's answer:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  by(df, list(df$Group, df$SubGroup), FUN = function(x) {
    within(x, {
      value_sum <- sum(Value)
      value_sum_dup1 <- sum(Value[Dup == 1])
      value_sum_dup0 <- sum(Value[Dup == 0])
      value_z <- sum(Value[Type == "Z"])
      value_y <- sum(Value[Type == "Y"])
      value_x <- sum(Value[Type == "Z"])
    })[1, ]
  })
)
```